# Bis Endes oder bis Ende?

Tags: genitive, accusative

In meinem Kursbuch (Menschen, Niveau B1.2) gibt es einen Satz,

> Die ersten Bauern der Gegend fällten Bäume und lebten bis Endes des 18. Jahrhunderts von ihren Schafen und Bienen sowie deren Wolle und Honig."

Ich weiß, dass nach dem Wort "bis" man Akkusativ benutzt, aber hier haben wir Genitiv. Und warum gibt es keinen Artikel vor dem Wort "Ende"? Das ist ein bestimmter Zeitpunkt, oder?

Comment: Meiner Ansicht nach ist das ein Fehler im Buch. Korrekt ist "bis Ende".

Comment: Auch das richtige "Ende" ist hier kein Akkusativ, sondern ein Dativ: "bis *zu dem* Ende"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das ist schlicht falsch - psychologisch vielleicht zu erklären als eine *Antizipation* des ähnlich klingenden nächsten Wortes (wie es auch in handgesetzten Texten manchmal vorkommt), aber grammatisch hat es keinen Sinn.

Answer (score 3):

*Bis* verbindet sich mit einem Akkusativ, deshalb handelt es sich um einen Fehler im Buch.

> bis nächst**en** Monat, nächst**es** Jahr, nächst**e** Woche

Wie die obigen Beispiele zeigen, verbindet *bis* sich normalerweise mit Nominalgruppen ohne Artikel. Dazu passt vielleicht auch, dass *bis* als temporale Präposition sich oft mit den Namen von Tagen oder Monaten verbindet, wo ebenfalls kein Artikel steht.

> bis Montag, bis August

Oft folgt auf *bis* eine weitere Präposition. Dann bestimmt die zweite Präposition den Kasus der Nominalgruppe. Beispiele mit Dativ:

> bis zu**m** bitteren Ende, bis nach d**er** Wahl

Answer (score 1):

Der Satz ergibt in vielerlei Hinsicht wenig Sinn.

1. grammatikalisch müsste es "...bis zum Ende..." heißen
2. Im letzten Teil des Satzes ergibt das Wort "sowie" inhaltlich keinen Sinn. "Sowie" dient als Verknüpfung von Gliedern einer Aufzählung (ähnlich wie das Wort "und"). Hier ist aber die Wolle und der Honig Produkte aus der vorherigen Aufzählung "Schafen und Bienen". Als Muttersprachlerin würde ich sagen "von ihren Schafen und Bienen - deren Wolle und Honig."

Comment: Das scheint mir offensichtlich genug, dass das schon korrekt ist. Von den Bienen kann man tatsächlich nicht leben (nur von deren Honig), aber Schafe kann man ja auch schlachten.

Comment: @PMF: auch von den Bienen kann man leben - indem man sich ihrer Erzeugnisse (Honig, Wachs, ...) bemächtigt. "Ich lebe von meiner Frau" heißt ja auch nicht, daß ich Kannibale bin, sondern Hausmann.

Comment: @PMF: "sowie", "oder" und "und" dienen der Verknüpfung von Gliedern einer Aufzählung. Hier sind aber "Wolle und Honig" keine Glieder der Aufzählung von "Schafen und Bienen" sondern Teilbereiche dieser Aufzählen.

Comment: Ich bin ebenfalls über das *sowie* gestolpert, aus dem gleichen Grund. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt zwar eine altertümliche Formulierung *bis Ends des* + Zeitpunkt. Eine ähnliche Formulierung ist im heutigen Schweizerdeutsch zu finden, allerdings nicht mit einem Zeitpunkt, sondern einer Zeitspanne, beispielsweise *bis änds Monet/Wuche/Jahr*.

Darum dürfte es hier aber schwerlich gehen. Stattdessen ist die Formulierung in dem Lehrbuch wohl als Teil einer Finde-die-Fehler-Übung zur Korrektur gedacht.